# How to email with user input without leaving the page after submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have page (contact me.php). I would like user to input their enquiry and email and submit.

I only know how to submit to the next page and gives a redirect back to the page.

How do i code in such a way that when user submit, it stays on the same page and display a notification like "Enquiry sent"

thanks many!

Comment: Use Ajax as @JohnRobertson said

Comment: You put the AJAX tag in your question, so it seems like you know the answer.

Comment: @Barmar yeah, i read up on articles and it says ajax is the solution but i'm only familiar with ajax

Comment: Then you need to learn it. SO is not a free code-writing service, you need to make an attempt and we'll help you fix the problems in it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to Send Email Form using Ajax like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'mail file url',
  type: 'post',
  data: {'action': 'data1': 'value1'},
  success: function(data, status) {
    if(data == "ok") {
      //your success message here 
    }
  },
  error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
    console.log(xhr);
    console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
  }
}); // end ajax call
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use AJAX.
By using AJAX, not need to update whole page.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code to send the email in a file and call $.ajax() if you plan to use jQuery. Simply pass the form data as either POST or GET variables to this file.

You can echo back to the calling page a value for success or error and handle this appropriately in the calling page.

Don't forget to check the variables you pass from the form using filter_var() etc.

Answer (score 0):

Call this function  through Ajax you can send email.  it will send email without reload.

```
function sendemail(){

var id=document.getElementById("email_id").value;
var msg=document.getElementById("message").value;

$.ajax({
url: 'mail.php?email_id='+id+"&message='+msg,
type: 'post',
data: {'action': 'data1': 'value1'},
success: function(data, status) {
if(data == "ok") {
  //your success message here 
}
},
error: function(xhr, desc, error) {
console.log("error" + error);
}
});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use html and jquery however your php would pretty much stay the same. I have included the html and jquery below. you can do the contact us page the way you normally do it.

```
----------



<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Contact Us</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>


    $(function() {

      $("#Send").click(function(){
        var name =$("#name").val();
            $.post('contactus.php',{Name:name},function(data)
                        {

                            alert(data);

                            });




        };


   });


    </script>
</head>
<body>  
    <form method="post" onsubmit='return false;' id="form">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" required id="name"><br>

        <input type="submit" id="Send" value="Send">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send email using php mail function or you can use some other plugin like [PHPmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)

And after you send email, you can direct your page in the same page use php syntax
header("Location: yourpage.php")

That's what i use

Hope it can help you

Answer (score 0):

look both link which have contact form with ajax request

http://www.elated.com/articles/slick-ajax-contact-form-jquery-php/

http://www.sanwebe.com/2011/12/making-simple-jquery-ajax-contact-form